# Exporting Javadoc to Markdown and then using Jade to generate a references website.

Tags: eclipse, pug, markdown, javadoc

I'm trying to export javadocs for a coding library. I need to convert the JDocs to markdown which can then be picked up by Jade templating engine or CMS like woods to create a website similar to paperjs (https://github.com/paperjs/paperjs.org) or P5js. Javadocs will need to be automatically translated into the references page similar to references page for P5js

I'm currently able to generate Jdocs using default settings from eclipse. https://code.google.com/p/ketai/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fketai%2Freference

Also, I was able to run woods but other parts of the workflow are missing. Any clue on how to figure out the process for that? How to convert Javadocs to markdown which can then be read by woods to be translated into static HTML pages?

Comment: P5js Reference Page - http://p5js.org/reference/#group-Environment